# Is there a significant difference between using a in built random number generator vs using cryptographic random number generator?

Tags: c++, random, cryptography, crypto++

I was going through the Crypto++ library [RNG page](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator#Example_Generator) and I was wondering is there any issues with using something like

```
 std::srand(std::time(nullptr)); //using the current time as seed
```

compared to the one of the rng in crypto library?

I'm beginner in cryptography, but one possible argument could be that the crypto rng functions are collision resistant ? However, I'm not sure how much better/stronger they are quantitively

Comment: The oseudo#random number generators in the standard library are not designed to be cryptographically secure. They’re intended for simulations and things of that nature.

Comment: `std::srand` is also not a random number generator.  Are you asking about `std::rand()`?

Comment: Depending on your platform `RAND_MAX` could be as little as 32767.

Comment: `std::srand()` and `std::rand()` are not required to meet any particular requirements for randomness, let alone for cryptographics.   And the sequence is predictable, if you know (or can guess the seed).    While they have their uses (easier to use than higher quality generators, and not every application requires a high quality generator) they will not usually be used to meet cryptographic requirements (unless you have a requirement of "easily broken" or "easily decrypted").

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but yes, I was asking about `std::rand` but I learned something about srand as well so thanks :)

Comment: @Peter — “high quality” depends on your requirements. For simulations, speed is critical and security is not. Cryptographically secure random number generators are low quality in that environment because they are too slow.

Comment: @PeteBecker  Agreed.   My previous comment focused on quality in terms of properties of the set of random values generated, since the OP referenced cryptography (which is associated with security measures).   But you're right in pointing out that different applications use different quality measures.

Comment: Collision resistance is not much of a thing for RNG's. If you expect random output then it should not collide ever when you get enough data. A bigger problem is that if you get to the (initial) state then you can predict all the following values. Usually functions like `rand` simply have a small enough state that you may even be able to brute force it, although generally you should be able to get to the state much quicker (e.g. by guessing the seed, or reversing the algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-cryptographic "random" sources are not suitable for cryptographic purposes because while they may produce values which are indeed different, the values may at least..

- perhaps have a predictable seed (often the time - predicting when a program started can cut the real entropy down to a few orders of values)
- perhaps rely on other low system entropy (consider a cloned VM between runs)
- behave badly or be logically less-complex in different environments (perhaps they use `size_t` and then target a 16 or 32-bit microcontroller)
- come from a quite limited pool (see [DOOM `m_random.c`](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/linuxdoom-1.10/m_random.c) for an extreme case)
- even if the pool is large, a subset of the results may be sufficient to predict upcoming values if the ordering is always the same
- not be produced in constant time (potentially leaking information about internal state)

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

There is a ***huge*** difference.

---

There are four classes of “random” numbers, categorized by the cross-section of two basic properties:

```
         insecure                secure
   ┌──────────────────┐   ┌──────────────────┐
 p │       PRNG       │   │      CSPRNG      │
 s ├──────────────────┤   ├──────────────────┤
 e │      rand()      │   │                  │
 u │       LCG        │   │   /dev/urandom   │
 d │ Mersenne Twister │ ← │   MS CryptoAPI   │
 o │    XOR Shift     │   │  (and many more) │
   │       etc        │   │                  │
   └──────────────────┘   └──────────────────┘
                                   ↑
   ┌──────────────────┐   ┌──────────────────┐
   │       TRNG       │   │      STRNG       │
 t ├──────────────────┤   ├──────────────────┤
 r │  Noise Sampling  │   │  (a TRNG that    │
 u │ Radioactive Decay│   │     has been     │
 e │ Lightning Strikes│ → │   unbiased, or   │
   │ Double Pendulums │   │    “whitened” )  │
   │       etc        │   │                  │
   └──────────────────┘   └──────────────────┘
```

The pseudo-random numbers are the ones people tend to think of when we say “random number library”.

The insecure numbers are useful only for things like video games and other non-critical stuff.

**Anything to do with security or cryptography, however, has to come from the *secure* side**. Since it is possible to exhaust a STRNG we use CSPRNGs for just about everything. CSPRNGS are no less secure than a STRNG.

<sup>The arrows in the above diagram show the direction of travel for things like initialization and entropy renewal — something you probably don’t have to care about.</sup>

---

The C++ Standard Library, with one (possible) exception, is all insecure PRNGs.

The *only* CSPRNG in the standard library (probably) is `std::random_device`, and it sucks. (Its various implementations have improved significantly since its introduction, but it is still a truly awful thing. I detest it so much I even wrote a small library to replace it in 2017<sup>[1]</sup>: https://github.com/Duthomhas/CSPRNG )

However, if you are working with a specific cryptography API, **stick with that**. It may not be particularly C++ friendly, but it provides superior facilities to do what you intend to do with it.

If you really want to learn more about this stuff, I recommend taking a University-level course somewhere at the 300-level. Most of the stuff you can find on the internet about cryptography and security is diluted by nonsense written by well-meaning folks who don’t know what they’re talking about, leaving beginners with a really muddled view of it all.

<sup>1 • Way back when one popular implementation was still implementing [Randall Munroe’s joke](https://xkcd.com/221/) as a placeholder. More good reading at [explainxkcd.com](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/221:_Random_Number).</sup>